# How to convert this raw query to Active record query interface or arel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel

I want to find `courses` which have at least 1 `variant` with `variant_type` = 1 and don't have any `variant` with `variant_type` = 2.

So my query like:

```
Course.where("id IN ( SELECT course_id
                     FROM course_variants
                     WHERE variant_type = 1
                   )
             AND id NOT IN (
                     SELECT course_id
                     FROM course_variants
                     WHERE variant_type = 2
                   )")
```

Additionally, a `course` has many `course_variants`.

I'm using a raw query in where clause, I want to improve this using Active record interface or Arel, any solution for this?

Thank you!

## Update with expected output with input

Input

```
course: {id=1, course_variants: [{variant_type: 1}, {variant_type: 2}]}
course: {id=2, course_variants: [{variant_type: 1}, {variant_type: 3}]}
course: {id=3, course_variants: [{variant_type: 2}, {variant_type: 3}]}
```

Output

```
course: {id=2, course_variants: [{variant_type: 1}, {variant_type: 3}]}
```

Comment: What values does `variant_type` can take? only 1,2,3 or unlimited numbers?

Comment: The variant_type is an enum, the range values would be [1..4]

Comment: As you are trying to exclude the `variant_type` with 2, try this query `Course.includes(:course_variant).where.not(course_variants: {variant_type: 2})`

Comment: It won't work correctly, since I also need variant_type = 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may tweak your model association a bit:

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :type_1_variants, class_name: "CourseVariant", -> { where(variant_type: 1) }
  has_many :non_type_3_variants, class_name: "CourseVariant", -> { where.not(variant_type: 3) }
end

Course.joins(:type_1_variants, :non_type_3_variants).group(:course_id).having('COUNT(course_variants.id) > 0').having('COUNT(non_type_3_variants_courses.id) > 0')
```

You may need to replace 'non_type_3_variants_courses' with the proper alias name that ARel generates when doing joins (I don't have a Rails env atm)

Comment: @HieuPham is this query really return your expected output??

Comment: @HoanNguyen for each variant_type condition you can write new association??

Comment: @VishalJAIN My idea was to abstract the conditions into something readable, let the framework generate SQL(s) which it sees best. It's a pity that ActiveRecord does not support advanced query as Django offers, hence I still had to stick with some raw queries above. Back to your question, if the conditions are dynamic, unpredicted..., it's better to generate raw SQL like the OP did.

Comment: @HoanNguyen I think you can provide/change it ti `ActiveRecord` query for above so that we can just change `variant` related condition in query. you can check my response.

Answer (score 1):

You should use joins method to join two tables `courses` and `course_variants` then define condition in where method, something like this:

```
Course.joins("INNER JOIN course_variants on courses.id = course_variants.course_id")
      .where("course_variants.variant_type" => 1)
```

Comment: Check out my update with expected input, output, your query will return courses with id in [1, 2], that is not an expected result

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Course.where(id: CourseVariant.where(variant_type: 1).pluck(:course_id)).where.not(id: CourseVariant.where(variant_type: 2).pluck(:course_id))
```

Hope this help. :)

Comment: I expect that it would run a single query!

Answer (score 1):

Hey you can try this way it is optimised way to find such records and here no need fire in clause two times:

You can do this in Rails pluck for second query as:

```
 Course.joins(:course_variants).where(:course_variants => {:variant_type => 1}).where("courses.id not in (?)",CourseVariant.where(:variant_type => 2).pluck(:course_id))
```

You can use in query internally in single query which is faster than above:

```
Course.joins(:course_variants).where(:course_variants => {:variant_type => 1}).where("courses.id not in (select course_id from course_variants where variant_type = 2)")
```

You can do this by using `group` in single query for mysql as:

```
Course.joins(:course_variants).group("course_variants.course_id").having("SUM(CASE WHEN variant_type = 1 THEN 1 
    WHEN variant_type = 2 THEN 2 
    ELSE 0 
    END) = 1")
```

Comment: Could we use rails way, but just use a single query?

Comment: Hey you can check my latest response using `group` and both are rails ways i mention there sql way because the in query fire internally. there is no way like sql and rails

Comment: @HieuPham is this work for you?? if any issues let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an association betweeen Course and CourseVarint models, then you can do as follows:

```
Course.joins(:course_variants).where(course_variants: {variant_type: 1}).where.not(course_variants: {variant_type: 2})
```

Comment: This will make three database queries, not suitable answer.

Comment: @Sakshi: I expect a single query for this? Thanks for your answer, could you update it?

Comment: @HieuPham I have updated the answer with some refactoring. You can try out.

Comment: It is still incorrect, could you check with my input/ and expected output for further update?

Comment: There is no error here, my query works well, I'm finding a way to improve it!

Comment: @SakshiJain your query return all `Courses` having `variant_type` is `1` which includes `courses` having `variant_type` is `2` because its first variant_type is 1