# SQL selecting users with specific type of cars

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Customer has_many cars
each Car belongs to ManufacturingPlant
ManufacturingPlant has an attribute called :country

How to find Customer whose car is not manufactured in India?

```
Customer.joins(:cars).where.not(cars: {manufacturing_plant_id: ManufacturingPlant.find_by_country("india").id})
```

In this case, if a user has a car made in China and in India, the user should not be shown up in the result since he has a car manufactured in an Indian plant. But with the above query it does.

Also, how can we write a query that doesnt use any of array operations eg IN ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey you can try this way:

For more info refer somewhat similar [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37106706/how-to-convert-this-raw-query-to-active-record-query-interface-or-arel/37178252#comment61895097_37178252)

```
Customer.joins({cars: [:manufacturing_plant]}).group("cars.customer_id").having("SUM(CASE WHEN manufacturing_plant.country = 'india' THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
        END) = 0")
```

Comment: So for my requirement, it should be `Customer.joins(cars: :manufacturing_plant).group("customers.id").having("SUM(CASE WHEN manufacturing_plant.country = 'india' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0")`

Comment: can you confirm the grouping clause?

Comment: grouping clause is ok. confirm means what??

Comment: In the group method, if I give "cars.customer_id", I get this error. PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "customers.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Comment: @MIdhunKrishna in PG you have to only select column by which you are grouping so you need to manually select column. in my case `cars.customer_id`  or if you are grouping using `customers.id` then select `customers.id`

Answer (score 1):

Some group by and having SQL operations with grouping by user_id and "casing" plant_id to check for "india_make" flag could work. SQL would be like this

```
select user_id, sum(CASE WHEN car.plant_id in [1,2, ..] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as if_india_made
from users, cars
where user.user_id = car.user_id
group by user.id
having if_india_made = 0;
```

Not sure if you can put it inside "nice" ActiveRecord code though

[here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7888f9/2) this is illustrated in SQL using SQL Fiddle (no joining tables there but the concept should be clear. [Same](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0a21b5/1) with casing inside having clause

Answer (score 0):

You can try find all the customers with a car made in either India or China first

```
class Customer
  scope :with_cars_made_in, -> (countries) { joins(cars: :manufacturing_plant).where("manufacturing_plants.country" => countries) }
```

Then the customers who don't cars made in either India or China would be like

```
@customers = Customer.where.not(id: Customer.with_cars_made_in(["China", "India"]).pluck("customers.id"))
```

Comment: This will create a query like `SELECT "customers".* FROM "customers" WHERE ("customers"."id" NOT IN (id_1, id_2, ...))`. Is there a way we can achieve this without matching id on a set? The reason being the in my specific case, the set has 20K+ items.

Comment: Changing `pluck` to `select` will produce a nested query / sub query: `SELECT "customers".* FROM "customers" WHERE ("customers"."id" NOT IN (SELECT "customers"."id" FROM "customers"....))..`